# Incomplete java byte code

Tags: java, bytecode

Hi I have follwoing java code,

```
public class A{
private String B="test_string";
private int AA;
public int C;
private int method1()
{
    int a;
    a=0;
    return a;
}


private int method1(int c, String d)
{
    int a;
    a=c;
    return a;
}
}
```

but when I used javap -c command to get equivalent byte code I get,

```
    Compiled from "A.java"
public class A extends java.lang.Object{
public int C;

public A();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   aload_0
   5:   ldc #2; //String test_string
   7:   putfield    #3; //Field B:Ljava/lang/String;
   10:  return

}
```

I am not clear about the byte code here, because where is the private variable and method declarations?

Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need the `-p` option to show private members:

```
javap -c -p A
```

You'll then see everything:

```
Compiled from "A.java"
public class A {
  private java.lang.String B;

  private int AA;

  public int C;

  public A();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1        // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0       
       5: ldc           #2        // String test_string
       7: putfield      #3        // Field B:Ljava/lang/String;
      10: return        

  private int method1();
    Code:
       0: iconst_0      
       1: istore_1      
       2: iload_1       
       3: ireturn       

  private int method1(int, java.lang.String);
    Code:
       0: iload_1       
       1: istore_3      
       2: iload_3       
       3: ireturn       
}
```

Comment: why I do not see the variable names in private methods? I can see class field names.

Comment: @Pbasak: Use `-v` to get verbose information, which will show local variable names. (It's not a matter of public/private - it's local variables vs fields.) You may also need to compile with `-g` for the local variable names to be included at all.

Comment: well having -v does not include variable names only some line number table, but compiling with -g can do that.

Comment: @Pbasak: Well -v will only display the variable names *if they're in the class file* obviously. You need to separate in your mind the difference between "information provided by the compiler" and "information shown by javap" - where the latter obviously has to be a subset of the former.

Comment: I see, that's may be the reason, decompilers cannot reproduce private variable names of the methods.

Comment: @Pbasak: Well not if the information isn't in the file they're reading, no. But they can if the compiler included that information in the class file - which is what the `-g` flag does.